# How to make issues-only repository on GitHub?

Tags: github, issue-tracking

To track private repository issues publicly, it is recommended to create issues only repository. Additionally, it is said to set "permissions you desire" here: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issues-only-repository/

Unfortunately, I can find, where to set any permissions on my issues repository. Looks like anybody can add and delete files from it.

Why and how to avoid this?

Comment: I believe the permission are: setting the repo to be public/private, protecting master branch from push/delete etc. As they have mentioned in the link you gave, you just have to create a repo, while creating it, set to public, and then a readme explaining the purpose of it.

Comment: But anyone will be able to push files or delete or substitute readme?

Comment: No one can push to a repository without necessary credentials. You can protect the master branch from repo settings to prevent anyone from pushing. Also, if you are in a organisation, unless the user is added to the repo with more-than-a-member access, he can't push/modify the repo. If you are owner of the organisation, you can put people in groups and micro manage who can access what repo. If the repo is under your profile, then there is no way anyone can push to it, unless that person is a collaborator.

Comment: "Looks like anybody can add and delete files from it." What makes you think that?